# Tensorflow image classification for 3 labels stuck at 0.33 accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I've been following this TensorFlow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) but wanted to try it with 3 labels instead of 2, so I added the softmax activation function to the prediction layer and changed the loss function from Binary to CaterogicalCrossentropy, but I'm still stuck at the initial 0.33 accuracy. Here's my code:

```
images = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))) + '/Images'
data_dir = pathlib.Path(images)
image_count = 1500
batch_size = 32
img_height = 160
img_width = 160

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.3,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size
)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.3,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size
)

class_names = train_ds.class_names

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1. / 255)

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))

train_dataset = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
validation_dataset = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

preprocess_input = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input

IMG_SIZE = (img_width, img_height)
IMG_SHAPE = IMG_SIZE + (3,)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_dataset))
feature_batch = base_model(image_batch)

base_model.trainable = False
global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
feature_batch_average = global_average_layer(feature_batch)

prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
x = inputs
x = preprocess_input(x)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

base_learning_rate = 0.0001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


initial_epochs = 50

loss0, accuracy0 = model.evaluate(validation_dataset)

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                    epochs=initial_epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_dataset)
```

Comment: Change the number of your output layer to your number of classes.

Comment: Thank you, I also added "label_mode='categorical'" option to the creation of datasets.